# Dismiss TabBarController From one of it's UINavigationControllers and return to the Controller from where the TabBarController was presented

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am presenting a `UITabBarController` from another `ViewController` (HomeViewController). The `TabBarController` in turn contains `UINavigationControllers`. However, when from one of the navigation controllers, the user presses the home button, he is required to go to the original `ViewController` from where the `TabBarController` was presented.

**`tabBarController` is not the rootViewController of my window.

Here's my code.

In `AppDelegate`, I am creating and configuring my `TabBarController`.

```
self.custCareVC = [[CustomerCareViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerCareViewController_iPhone" bundle:NULL];
        self.POController = [[PurchaeOrderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PurchaeOrderViewController_iPhone" bundle:NULL];
        self.accAndContactsController = [[AccountsAndContactsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AccountsAndContactsViewController_iPhone" bundle:NULL];

self.customerCareNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.custCareVC];
    self.customerCareNavController.title = @"Customer Service";

    self.purchaseOrderNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.POController];
    self.purchaseOrderNavController.title = @"PO";

    self.accAndContactsNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.accAndContactsController];
    self.accAndContactsNavController.title = @"Accounts And Contacts";

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    //self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bluehead.png"];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.customerCareNavController, self.accAndContactsNavController, self.purchaseOrderNavController, nil];
```

In my HomePageViewController, i am presenting it in the following way (on click of a button):

```
AppDelegate *appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDel.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:appDel.tabBarController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Now i need to dismiss my tabBarController after a user presses a Button on any of the navigation controllers (present in the tabBarController) and show the HomeViewController again..!!

Comment: Why can't you dismiss your TabBarController? Simply dismiss it. It will work.

Comment: It is not.. I have presented it from another ViewController. So, i need to dismiss it from there. When a user presses the home button on one of the navigationControllers of the tabBarController, he needs to get back to the controller from where the tabBarController was presented. what should i write in the -(IBAction) of the homeButton method (which when pressed will take the user to the home page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function in your target controller (which has the power to dismiss the `tabBarController`) and call that function from your topmost(current) controller/ controller the user is currently interacting with. To achieve the above, you need to first get the `tabBarController` object from the current controller using parent view controller. Then get the parent view/ root view controller of that controller and `performSelector` (function) which you created in the first controller.

Be sure to check `doesRespondToSelector` before you call `performSelector`so as to avoid any nasty crashes.

Another way, though pretty hackie is to store a weak reference of the first controller in the AppDelegate and access the same from you current controller.

Comment: This is a tested and verified method, feel free to ask if you get stuck anywhere. And I'll suggest that you don't follow that second method I suggested if you want to maintain a code standard.

Comment: I am pretty new to iOS. I am not exactly sure how to do above things you said. Can you post some code here?

Comment: You need to get the parent view controller of the current controller using `controlName.parentViewController` and then get the parent/ root view controller of that (depending upon your implementation). The best way to do it is to keep printing the objects received as the parentViewController/ rootViewController and that would print the class of the object. This would help you identify whether you are going on the right track or not. In case you are still having difficulties, I'll put the code; give it a shot, it's not that difficult :)

Comment: UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;
    
    UITabBarController *tabBarReference = [controller parentViewController]; ok i got the reference of my tabbarcontroller.. next??

Comment: Now get the parentViewController/ rootViewController of that (and keep doing it again and again by adding the same lines of code with the correct variables of course) to get the target viewController. Just keep on printing all the parent/rootViewControllers you get to keep a track of where are you heading.

Comment: do i need to make an object of the class that has the power to dismiss the tabbarcontroller, and then call the required method of dissmissViewController.. but the method is [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; how do i pass the reference of my tabBarController to this method??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43094/discussion-between-coder123-and-akshat-singhal)

Comment: @Akshat Singhal can you provide swift code on hoe to do this?

Comment: @user2363025 sorry I am not experienced with Swift.. You can let me know in case you are stuck somewhere, can help you out there.